# Bamboo taking too long to checkout code from SVN after upgrading bamboo to version 5.5

Tags: svn, bamboo, svn-checkout

After upgrading bamboo to version 5.5 the code checkout time has increased significantly, i have tried the solution - exchange the existing /webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jna-3.4.0.jar with the attached jna-3.3.0.jar file. but it didn't work for me, In Source Code Checkout i have not checked force clean build option. But still it checks out the whole code whenever a new build is fired. Is there any way with which the could should get updated once it has been checked out so that complete build process takes less time. Or if there is any other way please suggest. Thanks in advance.